# why calling curl from execSync in Node.js fails but directly run the exact-same command works?

Tags: node.js, curl, cookies

I have come into a trouble that when using `execSync` in node.js, it's not working as directly type the command in the shell.

Here is my issue:

I use a `curl` to request for some data from a server, and I need to do that with a cookie because there is a login requirement.

It's easy to handle the login process and get the cookie, but it's weird that using the cookie with a `curl` in node.js would cause the server an "internal error". And since I don't have the permission to change the server-code, I'm looking for help about the difference of calling `curl` in Node.js and directly use `curl`.

Here is the code:

```
var command = 'curl --cookie cookie.txt ' + getURL();
console.log(command);
// output: curl --cookie cookie.txt http://example.com/getdata
var result = child_process.execSync(command).toString();
// will cause an internal error and the "result" is an error-reporting page.
```

Directly calling this in the shell:

```
curl --cookie cookie.txt http://example.com/getdata
```

Everything works, I got the data I need.

I tried to find some plots, for instance, changing the code to:

```
var command = 'curl --cookie cookie-bad.txt ' + getURL();
```

I put some wrong cookie in the `cookie-bad.txt`, I will get a "you are not log in" result.

So there must be something wrong with:

sending a cookie to the server to request some data with **curl** running inside a nodejs script with `execSync`.

Is there any way I can improve the code or something?

Answer (score 0):

What is your Node.js version? I don't have any problem with 10.16.0.

[image]

Comment: My node version is `12.1.0`